# Having multiple fonts in Graphic Paint Android

Tags: java, android, canvas, paint

I am trying to create a jpeg image using the below code :

```
Bitmap src = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(activity.getResources(), R.drawable.background_splash); // the original file yourimage.jpg i added in resources
           Bitmap dest = Bitmap.createBitmap(src.getWidth(), src.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

            String yourText = "My custom Text adding to Image";

            Canvas cs = new Canvas(dest);
            Paint tPaint = new Paint();
            tPaint.setTextSize(35);
            tPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);

        tPaint.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                    PATH_FONT_PUNJABI));

            cs.drawBitmap(src, 0f, 0f, null);
            float height = tPaint.measureText("yY");
            float width = tPaint.measureText(yourText);
            float x_coord = (src.getWidth() - width)/2;
            cs.drawText(yourText, x_coord, height+15f, tPaint); // 15f is to put space between top edge and the text, if you want to change it, you can
            try {
                dest.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, new FileOutputStream(new File("/sdcard/ImageAfterAddingText.jpg")));
                // dest is Bitmap, if you want to preview the final image, you can display it on screen also before saving
               System.out.println("Image Created");
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Now I want some text to be using the font A and some to use font B. How can I achieve this?

Thanks,

Aman

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to do it with 2 separate draw text commands.  Set the first font, draw string 1, set the second font, draw string 2.  If one string comes after the other you can get the size of the string as drawn with the Paint object's measureText or getTextBounds

Comment: Can you please explain with an help of example.